# REST API | Jersey jar | 405 error

Tags: java, rest, soap, jersey, httprequest

I am trying to do automate REST API through Java. For this, I am using Jersy jar.
I googled enough and was able to write a code that doesn't throw any exception. However, I am always getting **405 - Method not allowed** error response when I try to reach my project's endpoint and post the request. Same endpoint returns success response on Soap UI. And there are no headers required. Media type is JSON.

Basically, I just want to do the SOAP UI operation, but through Eclipse.
PS: I'm novice, any help is appreciated.

```
package sample;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.Builder;

public class Sample 
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget resource = client.target("https://endpoint-url/Resource");
        Form form = new Form();
        form.param("name", "bond");
        form.param("ID", "007");

        Builder request = (Builder) resource.request();
        request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Response response = request.get();
        if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Family.SUCCESSFUL) 
        {
            System.out.println("Success! " + response.getStatus());
            System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR! " + response.getStatus());    
//          System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the output I get.
Status - 405
Method not allowed.

Comment: Please share the service code

Comment: Service code?
You meant the one on the server side? If so, I don't think I have access to it :(

Comment: I'm not very rigid about using Jersey.. any alternative solution for my problem is welcome..

Comment: Simple: The server does not allow `GET` requests to https://endpoint-url/Resource

Comment: @LutzHorn
Oh ok.. Actually, I want to use `POST`. I do see an option - `Response response = request.post(entity);`
What should i pass for **entity**?

Comment: The entity would be the JSON body.

Comment: I tried passing `entity` from the answer below, but I am getting 400 error.
Can you please see my comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073652/rest-api-jersey-jar-405-error/41074282#41074282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the code [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/restful-java-client-with-java-net-url/) that worked wonders for me :)

Below is the working code:

```
package sample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JavaNetURLRESTFulClient
{

    private static final String targetURL = "https://endpoint-url/Resource";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {

            URL targetUrl = new URL(targetURL);

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String input = "{\"name\":\"bond\",\"Id\":007}";

            OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (httpConnection.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server:\n");
            while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            httpConnection.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

         }

        }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue at accept,get resource instead of Post resource
you aren't passing form parameter to resource method. That is reason getting issues.Check below

```
public class Sample  {
        public static void main(String a[])
        {

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget resource = client.target("https://endpoint-url/Resource");
            Form form = new Form();
            form.param("name", "bond");
            form.param("ID", "007");
            Builder request = (Builder) resource.request();
            request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);         
    Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
            if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Family.SUCCESSFUL) 
            {
                System.out.println("Success! " + response.getStatus());
                System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR! " + response.getStatus());     //          System.out.println(response);
                System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried modifying the code, but I'm getting 400 error.
I even tried `Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));` and `Response response = request.post(Entity.form(form));` but i get the same 400 response - **The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.**

Comment: I'm quite sure that I am using all the required attributes in my request (ie, `form.param(attribute,value)`) with correct values.

Comment: You told server encounter error,what error you getting in the body of your method with a NPE or something?.For above url with passing form parameters is it working on SOAP UI?

Comment: I'm not getting NPE or any exception. On the eclipse console, instead of seeing success response, I'm getting error response. As mentioned above, this is what I'm seeing - '**400 - The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details**'. And yes, with same parameters I'm getting success response for the same endpoint on SOAP UI.